# TryUpdateModel for a model containing a list removes information from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a big object that I resorted to serializing using `@Html.Serialize()`:

```
[Serializable]
public class ModelB
{
    public List<ModelA> ListOfModelA { get; set; }
    // more stuff
}
```

This object contains a list of objects from a class that contains several properties. Some of them I include them in my view, while other I do not even bother to put them as hidden fields, as I have them in my serialized model.

```
[Serializable]
public class ModelA
{
    public string StringA { get; set; }
    public string StringB { get; set; }
    // more stuff
    public string HiddenStringA { get; set; }
    public string HiddenStringB { get; set; }  
    // more stuff
}
```

Now, when I post back the form with my changes I reconstract my model and then I update it using the dictionary of values obtained from the form.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Deserialize] ModelTwo model,
                         FormCollection form)
{
    TryUpdateModel(model, form.ToValueProvider());

    // more stuff
}
```

I step in my code and just before I do the update, I see that my deserialized model contains a list ListOfModelA that in turn contains all the elements that should be there, and within them I can see all the HiddenStringA and HiddenStringB properties. Then I peek inside the form and I see a dictionary with keys like these:

```
ListOfModelA[0].StringA 
ListOfModelA[0].StringB
ListOfModelA[1].StringB
ListOfModelA[1].StringB
```

while there are NO keys for the rest of the properties like this one:

```
ListOfModelA[0].HiddenStringA
```

Next, I move one step further and I let the code do the TryUpdateModel. Now, looking inside the ListOfModelA property, all the elements have been replaced with new ones that have all the hidden values null. It is as if the update reconstructed whole elements (with the limited information it had), rather than updating only the properties for which it had information.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there a way to keep my model, and update only the properties that have keys in the dictionary?

Thanks,

Panos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is more complex than the one described above, but the solultion that I found for the specific design is along the following lines. I serialize the part of the model that is a list, and bind the whole model through an argument of the action. This way I avoid using the TryUpdateModel, although this is not what causes me the trouble. Then, I inject the non-null values into the deserialized model from the model created from the form, and lastly I point the corresponding part of the latter to the former.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ModelTwo model,
                         [Deserialize] List<ModelA> serializedList)
{
    serializedList.InjectFrom<NonNullLoopValueInjection>(model.ListOfModelA);
    model.ListOfModelA = serializedList;

    // more stuff
}
```

For the injection, I use [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) where `NonNullLoopValueInection` is defined below

```
public class NonNullLoopValueInjection : LoopValueInjection
{
    protected override bool AllowSetValue(object value)
    {
        return value != null;
    }
}
```

Maybe not the best design, but it is working, and it might lead me to something better. Any feedback is more than welcome.